# Неверная ссылка "Посмотреть описание метки"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

Ссылка **"Посмотреть описание метки"** ведёт сюда

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript

а ? должна

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по всему у всех меток так

Answer (score 1):

Тут дело скорее в не совсем корректном переводе, нежели ошибочной ссылке. Например, если глянуть на англоязычный сайт, то можно увидеть такое:

> [image: View tag]

Т.е. [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/3396) скорее должен быть как "Посмотреть метку" без упоминания какого-то описания. Тогда всё более менее становится очевидным. Если есть другие предложения по переводу - предлагайте в комментариях к этому сообщению (хотя я очень сомневаюсь что тут можно придумать что-то лучше этих двух очевидных слов).

В качестве альтернативы предложил фича-реквест на MSE о замене ссылки на страницу с детальным описанием метки: [Change "View tag" to "View tag info" in tag tooltip](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353365/339911)

### UPD:

Изменил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/3396) на "Посмотреть метку". Ждём новых ревизий. Текущая rev 2020.9.4.37557

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript - "Вопросы с меткой [javascript]"

Comment: хотя посмотреть описание метки было бы логичнее, может это "у них" ошибка? ведь "Вопросы с меткой" я увижу кликнув по метке, зачем дублировать ...

Comment: @qwabra сложно сказать. В принципе ссылка сейчас что для самой метки, что для "View tag" ведёт на одну и ту же страницу. Кажется, что можно было бы действительно вместо "View tag" сделать "View tag info". Но это надо уже на MSE предлагать тогда делать.

Comment: @qwabra опубликовал предложение на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353365/339911)